# "Ropes Proverbs" or "Rope Proverbs"?

Tags: adjectives, plural-forms, attributive-nouns

I found this page, which title is 'Ropes Proverbs'.
http://proverbicals.com/ropes/

I wonder if the plural form of the adjective ("ropes") is correct - or should it be "Rope proverbs" - or maybe something else?

And if "ropes" is wrong, how would you rephrase that to clarify it's about plural "ropes" rather than "rope", without making the title too cumbersome?

Answer (score 1):

The singular form is correct.  In a noun phrase like **rope proverbs**, "rope" is a [noun adjunct](http://tx.english-ch.com/teacher/chris/level-b/grammar-in-use-noun-adjuncts/), which is a noun that modifies another noun.  A noun adjunct is always singular.

- *horse race*, not "horses race"
- *apple tree*, not "apples tree"
- *noodle soup*, not "noodles soup"
  etc.

In the case of these proverbs that are about ropes, I would not try and make it obvious that the proverbs are about plural ropes, because they are not really about multiple ropes, they're about rope in general.

Comment: I'm well aware of the fact that the article is about both rope and ropes. The question was how to clarify it's about plural ropes, if you need to.